# scalability in client object model vs web services

Tags: sharepoint, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, sharepoint-clientobject

I have a app in which I need to query a sharepoint site via services. The app will be under heavy usage so performance and scalability will be two of my priorities.

I started to investigate which service approach is better and from a perf point of view it seems that client object model is the one officially [suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313619.aspx), but when I came to scalability I personally found that actually web services seem more potent than client object model. This is because it seems that web services have [async support for IO bound operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646724.aspx) rather than client object model that [doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28v=office.14%29.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Asynchronous_Processing). I say doesn't because as [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) said *the ability to invoke a synchronous method asynchronously does nothing for scalability* and I think BeginInvoke does just that.

I have to mention that I am using in my app C# 5 async/await feature in order to return the thread to the thread pool when queries are executed on the server.

My question is, what should weight more in order to take a decision?

**Edit**: It is worth to mention that I am not using the Silverlight CSOM, I am using the more generic .NET one.

Comment: That's Sharepoint. Logic doesn't hold with Sharepoint. Besides, you should be concerned about SERVER-side scalability, not client-side scalability. Besides, what do you mean `IO bound operations`? CAML queries? The load on the server is the same no matter how you submit the query

Comment: @Panagiotis, I am not too much concerned about server side scalability because the server in this case is all about hardware and configuration and on the other side the client is a server of its own in another design. I mean IO bound operations for all processing that happens on the SP server (parsing caml, executing SQL queries, reading files, etc)

Comment: You can use WCF Data Services to query/update items asynchronously. Finding the equivalent way to work with the client object model needs a bit more digging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer with no answer. :)

You are correct in that `BeginInvoke` is fake-asynchronous (i.e., it just issues the blocking call on a thread pool thread). So it would actually be worse, scalability-wise, than just invoking the blocking methods.

First, consider your scalability as compared to your Sharepoint server. If you're running on roughly equivalent hardware, then you probably don't need to scale any more than the Sharepoint server will. You would probably be fine with either solution.

If you do need to scale better (e.g., the Sharepoint server is a cluster or cloud, or if your machine is much lesser than the Sharepoint machine), then it requires more thought and likely testing.

The better performance in the client model is purely from its batching capabilities. So if your application won't use batching, then the (asynchronous) web services model would be better.

However, if your application uses batching *and* needs to scale better, then there isn't an answer. In this case, the only way to know is to build a test case both ways and measure it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even it's an answer without an actual answer it seems educated. I guess I will have to do some testing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the client object model not only provides, but sometimes **requires** asynchronous access. You can find more info in the [Data Retrieval Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539350%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but the short version is that:

1. You create and load one or more queries in a ClientRuntimeContext then
2. Execute all loaded queries either synchronously with [ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.executequery%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or asynchronously with [ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQueryAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667318%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with two callbacks for success or failure

You don't have to use BeginInvoke anywhere.

In fact, the Client object model in Silverlight provides only the Async method in which case you are forced to execute the call asynchronously.

The syntax is quirky, but the client object model targets .NET 3.5 and Silverlight, so it wasn't possible to provide a Task based interface. You can even argue that callbacks are somewhat simpler than the Begin/End pattern and definitelly better that raising completion events.

**EDIT**

As @alexb noticed, ExecuteQueryAsync is available only in Silverlight. There are other ways to work asynchronously though.

You can take advantage of Sharepoint's OData support to query lists using WCF Data Services. The query scenario is a bit similar, as you submit your query and wait for a callback when the results come in. In the meantime, you get access to a DataServiceQuery object that represents the asynchronous query.

This method uses REST/Json and therefore lighter on the wire than the web services. The LINQ and ORM-like API are also easier to work with compared to the web services.

Sharepoint's support is described in [Query SharePoint Foundation with ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535480%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and asynchronous querying is described in [How to: Execute Asynchronous Data Service Queries (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd756367%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For (1) I suppose you refer to batching, yes batching is a great feature, I am already taking advantage of it. It would have been great if there was an ExecuteQueryAsync in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll but unfortunately my client in this case is not a Silverlight application. Under the hood is all about using BeginGetRequestStream which for Silverlight is used but not in the other library.

Comment: It is true that I didn't mention that my client is not a Silverlight app. I edited my question

Comment: OUCH! Didn't notice ExecuteAsync is only for Silverlight! Sharepoint documentation SAX! There ARE ways to work async, but I'll have to dig a bit more ...